# Downloading the distribute_setup.py

Tags: postgis, ordnance-survey, united-kingdom

I need to download distribute_setup.py from the following website and the website seems to be broken, has anyone got an idea where else I can download this from?

http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py

I am following this:
https://github.com/AstunTechnology/Loader/wiki/Installation

to install a loader to finally convert an Ordnance Survey (OS) topographic layer (which is in .GZ format) into PostGIS format.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to explain the connection to GIS, please?  I notice that you have a [tag:PostGIS] tag so perhaps that `distribute_setup.py` is something related to PostGIS but I am not able to follow it either.

Comment: This question would also be relevant to find a new solution for the outdated instructions in OSGeo docs at https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/ExternalPythonPackages

Comment: Try getting it from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the link, I am just embarking on writing an address base premium parser, so this is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently updated the [Loader install instructions on the wiki](https://github.com/AstunTechnology/Loader/wiki/Installation) to use `pip` an alternative Python package manager which supersedes `easy_install`.